# aborting because of server version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, yum

I was trying to take schema backup with the help of pg_dump but it is failing with the following error.

```
# pg_dump -hq2vy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U username -n schema > ouput.sql
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.14; pg_dump version: 9.2.18
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

The installed version architecture is

## rpm -qa | grep postgresql93*

postgresql92-libs-9.2.18-1.59.amzn1.x86_64

So I tried to install the x64 version but also failed with the following error

```
# yum install  postgresql93-9.3.14-1.62.amzn1.x86_64
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql93.x86_64 0:9.3.14-1.62.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql93-libs(x86-64) = 9.3.14-1.62.amzn1 for package: postgresql93-9.3.14-1.62.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql93-libs.i686 0:9.3.14-1.62.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package postgresql93-libs.x86_64 0:9.3.14-1.62.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package postgresql93-libs.i686 0:9.3.17-1.63.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem.
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: you have to use either the same or later version's pg_dump because the older version doesn't understand the catalog differences in the newer version of pgsql. I.e. you can backup 9.3 with 9.4's pg_dump, because 9.4 pgdump understands itself and all previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by installing the package postgresql93.x86_64